# Cannot decode this json in php

Tags: php, json

I cannot decode this sample json in php.

```
{
  "1": {
    "pivot": "{\"pivot_main\":asdfasdf,\"adsffd\":\"abcd: 100% of \\\"pqrs\\\" is \\\"abcd\\\", 100% of \\\"abcd\\\" is \\\"Aa\\\", 100% of \\\"cfgh\\\" is \\\"zxcvnb\\\", 100% of \\\"ajsdf\\\" is \\\"laksjdbfkasjfbklasjdbfkahfbklasjdbflkjasdbflkajds\\\". \",\"responseType\":\"adsfasdfadsf\",\"adsfadsf\":3,\"asdfasdfa\":\"ajhsdbfjahsbdfajsdf\",\"asdfadf\":\"adsfasdfadf\",\"asdfafd\":\"asdfasdfasdfadsvzxcv\"}"
  }
}
```

`json_last_error()` gives me error code of 4, but I cannot recognise the error. My end goal is to read the `pivot_main` key in pivot parent key.

Comment: error code 4 means a syntax error. But https://jsonlint.com/ regards your sample JSON as valid. However it's possible that PHP's parser is having trouble with the fact that the "pivot" data is clearly double-encoded (i.e. it's a JSON string encoded as a string within another JSON string) and there are some over-escaped quote marks in there. Did you generate this sample JSON yourself from some other code? Because it's a mess - the double-encoding needs to be removed and then you'd have a lot less issues I think.

Comment: @ADyson I am receiving this sample json from a third party application. How to go about removing the double encoding that you have pointed out?

Comment: If you can influence what the 3rd party application does, I'd raise a bug with the people who maintain it and mention that their application is outputting junk data. (Unless of course it's actually the result of some user input where a user has pasted JSON into a text field or something. I have no way of knowing how the data actually got there,obviously, but maybe you do)

Comment: Failing that, it's tricky. Normally I'd say "decode the outer JSON, and then separately decode the inner JSON by reading from the specific property containing the double-encoded data"...but since PHP can't even do the first bit, it's a problem. My only suggestion is that you gradually remove unnecessary stuff from the double-encoded data until you can work out which bit(s) of text are causing json_encode to fall over, and then see if there's a way to automatically detect and remove those types of things from the string (e.g using string replace or regex) before you attempt parsing.

Comment: Obviously that's mucky and may not be very reliable, but if you're going to be getting ugly data like this on a regular basis and can't do anything to prevent it, then I don't see too many other options at the moment. Maybe someone else will have a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by making the inner json a valid one -

```
$json = '{
  "1": {
    "pivot": "{\"pivot_main\":asdfasdf,\"adsffd\":\"abcd: 100% of \\\"pqrs\\\" is \\\"abcd\\\", 100% of \\\"abcd\\\" is \\\"Aa\\\", 100% of \\\"cfgh\\\" is \\\"zxcvnb\\\", 100% of \\\"ajsdf\\\" is \\\"laksjdbfkasjfbklasjdbfkahfbklasjdbflkjasdbflkajds\\\". \",\"responseType\":\"adsfasdfadsf\",\"adsfadsf\":3,\"asdfasdfa\":\"ajhsdbfjahsbdfajsdf\",\"asdfadf\":\"adsfasdfadf\",\"asdfafd\":\"asdfasdfasdfadsvzxcv\"}"
  }
}';

$json = str_replace('\\\\', '\\\\\\', $json);
$a = json_decode($json, true);
```